# Can't filter cell with query inside in Google Sheet

Tags: function, google-sheets, filter

I have want to filter a column which i created by using the following formula:

=UNIQUE(Overall!A2:A614)

So basically it was to get unique value of data from a whole column from another sheet (overall)

[Here is the column I want to filter (in black)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHDjL.png)

But When I filter it A-Z or Z-A, blank cells appear with 0 everywhere and some of the data are put at the bottom of the column:

[Here is what I get when I filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7SgL.png)

Do you have an idea about it how to be able to filter my column without that problem ? Thanks !

I was expecting that the filter would just work without such problem.

Comment: try putting the formula in row 1 `={"";UNIQUE(Overall!A2:A614)}`

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer player0, like that it adds an empty cell (like total) it works the if i filter from A to Z but when I filter from Z to A it removes all data at the bottom and fill the with 0